# Best Approach for Google Drive Push Notifications for all users in a domain

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-admin-sdk, google-api-java-client, google-admin-audit-api

I want to set up real time notifications for all the users in my gsuite domains. I have approximately 10k users.

The approach, i am currently following is "watching the changes in drive of each user" i.e. using changes.watch api and changes.list api for each user drive.

I recently found out about drive audit admin api, that gives us a whole lot of control on user's drive activity. Also, it supports web-hooks on drive audit events so i can get the changes in real time.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-drive

Please suggest, which approach is better and why? The changes on user's drive or drive audit admin api.

Thanks.

Comment: One problem that i can see in audit drive solution is the quota imposed by google , it is significantly low as compared to the google drive api quotas -Queries per day -- 150,000 ,
Queries per 100 seconds per user  -- 1,500

Comment: Apart from the above two approaches, there is a third api -
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/activity/v1/reference/ , Now i am pretty much confused with the use-cases of all three apis. Please Help!!!